# Get ETH back from contract

Tags: transactions

I have created this contract and sent ETH to it. Now I want to send the ETH back to my main account, I have these options:

- removeOwner
- isOwnder
- m_numOwners
- m_lastDay
- version
- resetSpentToday
- m_spentToday
- addOwner
- m_required
- confirm
- setDailyLimit
- execute
- revoke
- changeRequirements
- hasConfirmed
- kill
- changeOwner
- m_dailyLimit

Which option do I use to transfer credit?

Comment: Unless it is a standard contract the function name can be misleading. Your contract seems to be a multisig wallet, in that case `kill` will remove the contract and refund the address provided.

Comment: can i use the "kill" command and put the desired destination into the "to -address" field?

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments if the contract you're talking about is this : https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/wallet/wallet.sol

Then you can call the kill method :

```
function kill(address _to) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data)) external {
    selfdestruct(_to);
}
```

It should return the fund to the address you're calling from. selfdestruct is an alias of the suicide method.